# The following binary tree program shows a runtime error saying min() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree

This is a tree question wherein, partition is made by breaking a branch and total file size is found by adding files_size in separate partition. Minimum diiference is to be found among these combinations.

```
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
# The function accepts following parameters:
#  1. INTEGER_ARRAY parent
#  2. INTEGER_ARRAY files_size
#

def mostBalancedPartition(parent, files_size):
    
    minimum = []
    for i,j in zip(parent, parent[1:]):
        if i == j:
            num_1 = 0
            num_2 = 0
            for index_1, size in enumerate(files_size):
                
                if index_1 > parent.index(i):
                    num_1 += size
                else:
                    num_2 += size
            minimum.append(abs(num_1 - num_2))
        else:
            pass
    return min(tuple(minimum))
```

Comment: Presumably `minimum` is empty - try adding a line before that and print `minimum`. Then look at your code and work out how that happens. For example, is it possible that `i == j` is never true?

Comment: And even if you think that `i == j` is always true at least once, add a line `print(f”{minimum=}”)` to confirm that a value is being appended to the list.